# Determining parent page of template

Tags: templates, grails, gsp

Inside a Grails GSP template (e.g., `_form.gsp`), how can I determine what page is calling the template (e.g., `create.gsp` or `edit.gsp`) so that different fields can be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way, no. If you just know that in your application that the `foo` action always renders the `foo` view and there aren't exceptions to that, then of course you can just look at the action name. You could also do something simple like put something in the model when rendering the template, like `<g:render template="foo" model="[parentPage:'edit']"/>`, or set a variable in pageScope or similar. There are ways to accomplish what you want, but no general way in a template to answer the question "What GSP rendered this template?". I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I googled it without any mention of templates (`gsp determine current page`) and found the answer on [this Nabble thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/how-to-get-controllername-and-actionname-in-main-gsp-td1358456.html).  I will use `params.action` to determine what action I'm currently doing (e.g., create or edit), and use that to display different fields.

Cheers!

Comment: Of course that depends a little on how your template is being used/rendered. If you are using g:include and calling an action through your controller to render said template then the action will be that of the call to the controller. However in this case, you could always pass along a parameter to the call indicating where it was called from by passing params.action for the value.

Comment: params.action does not tell you what page rendered a template. It tells you what controller action was invoked. There are lots of reasons that those might not be the same.

Comment: maybe knowing the action could fit in this problem, if this is true, you can access current action name in this way ${actionName} too.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, is there a way to determine the page then?

Comment: Although, really, action is sufficient to distinguish between `create` and `edit`. But now I want to know if there's a better way :)

Comment: There is no general way, no. If you just know that in your application that the `foo` action always renders the `foo` view and there aren't exceptions to that, then of course you can just look at the action name. You could also do something simple like put something in the model when rendering the template, like `<g:render template="foo" model="[parentPage:'edit']"/>`, or set a variable in pageScope or similar. There are ways to accomplish what you want, but no general way in a template to answer the question "What GSP rendered this template?". I hope that helps.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown indeed it does, thanks. I especially like the idea of keeping any such extra variables at as narrow a scope as possible (e.g., right in the `render` tag).